What is the formula that Azure Quantum Resource Estimator is using for codeDistance?
The Azure Resource Estimator generally talks about codeDistance and says "The code distance is a parameter that controls the number of errors that can be corrected". Is there a specific formula that the resource estimator is using to calculate this number?

If you run resource estimation and dig into the outputs, there's a section that explains where each number comes from. If you look there for a field named "logicalQubit/codeDistance", you'll find a message that starts with "The code distance is the smallest odd integer greater or equal to" followed by a formula with specific numbers for your case. I looked up this phrase in the source code at https://github.com/microsoft/qsharp/, and the file that is used to pretty print the results has the generic formula for this:
Code distance
Required code distance for error correction
The code distance is the smallest odd integer greater or equal to $\dfrac{2\log(\color{red}{\mathtt{jobParams/qecScheme/crossingPrefactor}} / \color{blue}{\mathtt{physicalCounts/breakdown/requiredLogicalQubitErrorRate}})}{\log(\color{red}{\mathtt{jobParams/qecScheme/errorCorrectionThreshold}}/\color{blue}{\mathtt{physicalCounts/breakdown/cliffordErrorRate}})} - 1$
(I highlighted different variables with different colors, as it easy to confuse slashes in variable names with slashes that are divisions - it's easier to read this formula for specific values.)
Taking more liberties with formatting...
The code distance is the smallest odd integer greater or equal to $\dfrac{2\log \left(\dfrac{\color{red}{\mathtt{jobParams/qecScheme/crossingPrefactor}}} {\color{blue}{\mathtt{physicalCounts/breakdown/requiredLogicalQubitErrorRate}}}\right)} {\log\left(\dfrac{\color{red}{\mathtt{jobParams/qecScheme/errorCorrectionThreshold}}}{\color{blue}{\mathtt{physicalCounts/breakdown/cliffordErrorRate}}}\right)} - 1$

Great, thank you so much Mariia!
